# Intellisense is not working in MVC 3 razor views

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Razor Intellisense Not Working VS2010 SP1Rel MVC3 from WPI Win7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133090/razor-intellisense-not-working-vs2010-sp1rel-mvc3-from-wpi-win7-x64)

Intellisense for the Razor view in asp.net mvc 3 is not working anymore? how can I restore this?

Comment: seen this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133090/razor-intellisense-not-working-vs2010-sp1rel-mvc3-from-wpi-win7-x64 ?

Comment: What did you do to make it stop working? Can you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling windows 7 and vs.net 2010 + sp1 and now it works:)

Comment: that sounds pretty extreme.  doubtful win7 had anything to do with the problem...

Comment: i love it when people are being smartass about "extreme" solutions when sometimes that's the only thing that works with MS software...