# ServiceStack Razor inherits directive has no intellisense

Tags: razor, servicestack

I'm learning ServiceStack razor and wanted to get better with it(ServiceStack in general), I can't get the intellisense to work on models(via **inherits** directive) though

[image]

Here's my attempt so far: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/12/self-hosting-servicestack-serving.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've explained the troubles I've had with getting [Razor Intelli-sense to work here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/issues/2#issuecomment-10934218) basically it's delicate to get it working that I've now decided it's better to first focus on upgrading to use the current (backward-incompatible) Razor v2.0 version before investing further effort in getting intelli-sense to work. This is something I plan to tackle in the near future.

BTW: Nice article Michael, I've added it to the [Wiki](http://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki) and [Community Resources](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Community-Resources).